# Unable to create hive external table in apache spark in Intellij

Tags: apache-spark, hive, external-tables

This the command I written for creating external table in Intellij

```
val ex_table= spark.sql("Create EXTERNAL TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS userdf.ex_table(Id Int,Name String,Time Timestamp) PARTITIONED BY(Location String) STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION 'C:\\Users\\XSA1BGP\\IdeaProjects\\Spark_Bigdata'");
//ex_table.describe()
```

It is not showing any exceptions but the table is not displayed yet

Comment: Your exceptions might be in the Spark UI, if there were any. Where are you checking if the table should be displayed?

Comment: I'm using intellij for my assignment so I'm checking out in project folder also in terminal

Comment: So, have you checked the Spark UI or not? If you're using cluster deploy mode, rather than local driver, the logs from the table creation are will be in the Spark UI

Comment: complete snippet is needed